# Rails 4 errors on simple migration on Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Not the first Rails 4 migration bug for Postgres that I've found, if indeed it is a bug.

I can't figure out why this extremely simple migration won't work:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, { default: false, null: false }
  end
end
```

I have tried it with and without the curly braces. Here is the error:

==  AddAdminToUsers: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:users, :admin, :boolean, {:default=>false, :null=>false})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/rails_best_practices-1.15.0/lib/rails_best_practices/core_ext/object.rb:7:in `try'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:723:in `translate_exception'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:439:in `rescue in log'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `log'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
```

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) is very clear that this is allowed:

```
add_column(table_name, column_name, type, options): 
  Adds a new column to the table called table_name named
  column_name specified to be one of the following types:
    :string, :text, :integer, :float, :decimal, :datetime,
    :timestamp, :time, :date, :binary, :boolean. 
A default value can be specified by passing an options
  hash like { default: 11 }. 
Other options include :limit and :null (e.g. { limit: 50, null: false })
```

Also, why is the `rails-best-practices` gem complaining? I'm not invoking it.

Comment: Remove the curly braces. See if that helps.

Comment: Only works if I delete everything after "boolean".

Comment: Are you using rails 4.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the `rails_best_practices` gem. When I uninstall that gem, the code works. I will inform the gem maintainer.

Comment: I think its was a known issue. That version has been yanked from ruby gems. Upgrade to version 1.15.1 that should fix the issue and keep the them installed.

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the case. The upgrade fixed the problem instantly. Great response by the gem team also.